# org-mode review clocked time by multiple tags

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to review my clocked time by tags, to answer e.g. how much time did I spend this week on my health, on my work, on a client or on social relationships?

I am using tags, because the items I want to review my clocked time, can be spread over multiple files and hidden in different subtrees. Maybe this is the problem and I need to restructure? E.g. "Write an entry in your diary" should be stored under "notes", but summed into "health" and of course under "notes" there would be also other notes like "finance"...

Any other solution, e.g. using a custom agenda view or categories instead of tags would also be very welcome.

So far I have tried to use [org mode clocktable](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html) grouped by multiple tags. For using clocktables I was using this test data:

```
* Take out the trash                                                :private:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2021-03-12 Fri 11:24]--[2021-03-12 Fri 11:30] =>  0:06
:END:
* Update document for client                                        :client1:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2021-03-12 Fri 12:45]--[2021-03-12 Fri 13:30] =>  0:45
:END:
* Create my awesome note for work                                      :work:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2021-03-13 Sat 11:24]--[2021-03-13 Sat 12:53] =>  1:29
:END:
* Fill in timesheet                                                    :work:
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2021-03-12 Fri 11:24]--[2021-03-12 Fri 11:40] =>  0:16
:END:
```

I have found the following solutions, neither seems to work with my system.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353591/timetable-grouped-by-tag) my problem is perfectly described. I've downloaded [the code](https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/5899058), it will create a table, but won't show the sums. Unfortunately, that code snipped seems too old, and I am not able to fix it. I have found a [a fork of that snipped](https://gist.github.com/ironchicken/6b5424bc2024b3d0a58a8a130f73c2ee) which gives me this result:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable-by-tag :tags ("work" "client1")
| Tag     | Headline   | Time (h) |
|         |            |      <r> |
|---------+------------+----------|
| work    | *Tag time* |   *0.00* |
|---------+------------+----------|
| client1 | *Tag time* |   *0.00* |    
#+END:
```

[Here](https://mpas.github.io/posts/2021/03/16/2021-03-16-time-tracking-with-org-mode-and-sum-time-per-tag/) I found another solution. The author uses a function to format the times, which are then used by [orgaggregate](https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate). Unfortunately already the first step, doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
 #+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 3 :tags t :match "work|client1" :header "#+TBLNAME: timetable\n"
#+TBLNAME: timetable
| Tags    | Headline                        |   Time | T      |
|---------+---------------------------------+--------+--------|
|         | *Total time*                    | *2:30* | #ERROR |
|---------+---------------------------------+--------+--------|
| client1 | Update document for client      |   0:45 | #ERROR |
| work    | Create my awesome note for work |   1:29 | #ERROR |
| work    | Fill in timesheet               |   0:16 | #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: $4='(convert-org-clocktable-time-to-hhmm $3)::@1$4='(format "%s" "T")
#+END:
```

It really shouldn't be that hard, what I would like to achieve. At the moment the best solution I have, is to use multiple tables, one for each tag:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 3 :match "work"
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2022-01-03 Mon 16:55]
| Headline                        |   Time |
|---------------------------------+--------|
| *Total time*                    | *1:45* |
|---------------------------------+--------|
| Create my awesome note for work |   1:29 |
| Fill in timesheet               |   0:16 |
#+END:


#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope file :maxlevel 3 :match "client1"
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2022-01-03 Mon 16:55]
| Headline                   | Time   |
|----------------------------+--------|
| *Total time*               | *0:45* |
|----------------------------+--------|
| Update document for client | 0:45   |
#+END:
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution you found was almost there. It had two issues that gave you the wrong result:

1. It considered only agenda files, not the current file as an input for the table. That's the reason why you were getting empty results.
2. To convert minutes to a nicely formatted display, the function `org-duration-from-minutes` can be used.

With these updates, your test file gave this result to me:

```
  #+BEGIN: clocktable-by-tag :tags ("work" "client1")
  | Tag     | Headline                          | Time (h) |      |
  |---------+-----------------------------------+----------+------|
  | work    | *Tag time*                        |     1:29 |      |
  |         | File *test.org*                   |     1:29 |      |
  |         | . Create my awesome note for work |          | 1:29 |
  |---------+-----------------------------------+----------+------|
  | client1 | *Tag time*                        |     0:45 |      |
  |         | File *test.org*                   |     0:45 |      |
  |         | . Update document for client      |          | 0:45 |
  
  #+END:
```

You can get a better summary by using `:summary t` (I personally prefer this option):

```
  #+BEGIN: clocktable-by-tag :tags ("work" "client1") :summary t
  | Tag     | Headline   | Time (h) |
  |---------+------------+----------|
  | work    | *Tag time* |     1:29 |
  |---------+------------+----------|
  | client1 | *Tag time* |     0:45 |
  
  #+END:
```

The `:scope` tag also works, except that I didn't implement scopes tighter than the current file (such as `subtree`).

You can find the code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nonducor/004b903670c83d88176ab2714e21b598), or copy and paste from below:

```lisp
(require 'org-clock)

(defun clocktable-by-tag/shift-cell (n)
  (let ((str ""))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (setq str (concat str "| ")))
    str))

(defun clocktable-by-tag/insert-tag (files params)
  (let ((tag (plist-get params :tags))
        (summary-only (plist-get params :summary))
        (total 0))
    (insert "|--\n")
    (insert (format "| %s | *Tag time* |\n" tag))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (file)
       (let ((clock-data (with-current-buffer (find-buffer-visiting file)
                           (org-clock-get-table-data (buffer-name) params))))
         (when (> (nth 1 clock-data) 0)
           (setq total (+ total (nth 1 clock-data)))
           (if (not summary-only)
               (progn
                 (insert (format "| | File *%s* | %s |\n"
                                 (file-name-nondirectory file)
                                 (org-duration-from-minutes (nth 1 clock-data))))
                 (dolist (entry (nth 2 clock-data))
                   (insert (format "| | . %s%s | %s %s |\n"
                                   (org-clocktable-indent-string (nth 0 entry))
                                   (nth 1 entry)
                                   (clocktable-by-tag/shift-cell (nth 0 entry))
                                   (org-duration-from-minutes (nth 4 entry))))))))))
     files)
    (save-excursion
      (re-search-backward "*Tag time*")
      (org-table-next-field)
      (org-table-blank-field)
      (insert (org-duration-from-minutes total))))
  (org-table-align))

(defun org-dblock-write:clocktable-by-tag (params)
  (insert "| Tag | Headline | Time (h) |\n")
  (let ((params (org-combine-plists org-clocktable-defaults params))
        (base-buffer (org-base-buffer (current-buffer)))
          (files (pcase (plist-get params :scope)
                     (`agenda
                      (org-agenda-files t))
                     (`agenda-with-archives
                      (org-add-archive-files (org-agenda-files t)))
                     (`file-with-archives
                      (let ((base-file (buffer-file-name base-buffer)))
                        (and base-file
                               (org-add-archive-files (list base-file)))))
                     ((or `nil `file)
                      (list (buffer-file-name)))
                     (_ (user-error "Unknown scope: %S" scope))))
        (tags (plist-get params :tags)))
    (mapcar (lambda (tag)
              (clocktable-by-tag/insert-tag files (org-combine-plists params `(:match ,tag :tags ,tag))))
            tags)))
```

Comment: If I include the variable `:sort (3 . ?t)` in the `#+BEGIN clocktable-by-tag` line it does not affect the outcome by sorting the `Time` table column. Should this variable be included directly in the function script to be effective?